# Query based on Today's date

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a Google Spreadsheets document with two sheets in it. The first sheet is where I want to run my query. Located in cell B1 is today's date with the formula `=today()`. I have headers in row 2. So I want the query to start in A3. My information is in the second sheet cells A38:M1267. I only want the query to pull columns B, D, F, K. Column A has the dates. I want to run the query based on today's date and match all the dates in column A of the second sheet and return the values.

The query formula I have tried:

```
=QUERY(Season!A38:M1257,"SELECT A,D,F,K, Where A ="&B1&"")
```

keeps coming up with `#Value`. I have spent the last few hours trying to rewrite it to get it to work and I just don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
=QUERY(Season!A38:M1257,"SELECT B,D,F,K where A = date '"&text(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: Thank You Worked just like I needed it to.